# What makes a UX User Story?

Tags: design-process, use-cases, agile-development, user-story

How does one create a user story as used in Agile methodologies? How should they be written; is there a standard?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Mike Cohn provides a [great template](http://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/topics/user-stories) for user stories which is used throughout the industry.

> As a *type of user*, I want *some goal* so that *some reason*.

- As a *customer*, I want *to pay my bill online* so that *I do not
  have to mail it in*.
- As a *developer*, I want *unit tests in place* so that *I can verify
  my code is functional*.
- As an *enterprise card holder*, I want *the ability to add
  sub-accounts* so that *I do not need separate accounts for my
  employees*.

Comment: Might note that long after this answer I continued researching the topic, and the shortest version of the user story template I found was: **"Who needs what, and why?"**

Comment: A lesson learned from the process of extracting these from Product Manager and stakeholders is that the there's usually a temptation to omit the 'why' part (presumably because it requires some thinking) and just describe '"Who needs what". The problem with this is that  the 'why' is often the most important part of the equation in order to make the best design decisions.

Answer (score 1):

In the book "Writing Effective Use Cases (Crystal Series for Software Development) from Alistair Cockburn" are some good use case technics and scenarios described. His text-based use case method is very efficient and fast.

In addition, I have another link to this topic:
http://gatherspace.com/static/use_case_example.html